# Newton's 3rd law and Tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, friction

Suppose I pull on a rope. where is the 3rd law reaction force ?

Is it the tension in the string which pulls me up or there exists some other force which is the reaction of my action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rope is attached to something solid at the upper end, then the rope reacts to your pull and the point of attachment reacts to the pull of the rope.

Comment: And what is that reaction force specifically?is it tension?